# How to check if app user is in Google Play Beta Testing

Tags: android, google-play, openid-connect, beta-testing

I understand that the Google Play Beta feature allows me to distribute APKs to a closed user group, but I also need to be able to verify if the people logging in after download using Google Login are also in the beta program of my app, in order to make sure that the APK isnt distributed & used without my knowledge.

Is there any way to check if a Google Login user is participating in beta testing with OpenID Connect or similar technologies?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could check if the user is on the testers list. On your backend, you just request the Google Play Console API: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/edits.testers/get